# Picture Box Erases Graphic in Panel

Tags: c#

I have a picture box that follows the mouse when it enters a panel where I draw objects. However the picture box as it follows the mouse erases any objects drawn in the picture box. How can I prevent this?

```
private void layout_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    PictureBox.Location = new Point(e.X -(componentsize/2),e.Y -(componentsize/2));      
}
```

Comment: Don't use CreateGraphics() to draw, use the Paint event.  And post relevant repro code to ask for help, this isn't it.

Answer (score 1):

When the picturebox moves over the panel WinForms calls redraw on the panel. If the code in the Paint event does not paint the correct image it will remain 'empty'.

You are most likely adding lines and shapes and such to the panel on mouse clicks. It would be better to add the lines and shapes to a list and call Refresh on the panel. In the paint event of the Panel draw all items of the list.

This way the panel will always (when redrawing, resizing, dragging stuff over) contain the correct contents.

Comment: Yes your are right thank you very much